# Forbid push notification dismissal

Tags: android, push-notification, dismiss

I'm using **Cordova Push plugin** (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/) and **GCM** for `push notifications`.

Is there any way via which I can **forbid the dismissal of the notification**? I want it dismissed only when it's clicked and the user has entered the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an "ongoing" Notification.

Simply add `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` to your flags.

Docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT

Comment: I still don't understand where I should add the flag. From my application server I send simple JSON to GCM, and then handling the notificationReceived event in my Cordova client app.

Comment: You add the flag to your notification builder. I'm not certain how that is accomplished with Cordova.